How do I format the groups to perform an ANOVA test in R?
I am needing to do an ANOVA test on four groups. The data are the top and bottom 20 heights for male and female, pulled from a larger set of data. The instructions provided to me are to simply run the test, but R is telling me they need to be in a matrix. The code I have is:
#assigning variables
msort <- sort(mdata[,2],decreasing = TRUE)
fsort<- sort(fdata[,2], decreasing = TRUE)
mt <- msort[1:20]
ms <- msort[4981:5000]
ft <- fsort[1:20]
fs <- fsort[4981:5000]

#the test
aov(ms~ft~mt~fs)

How do I put them into a matrix while retaining the same meaning/categorization? And what would the formula be?
I tried just doing as.matrix(), but this just put all the values from the groups into one column with no other labels, which is expected, I suppose. I am unable to pull the same sorted numbers from the original data frame, which had 10000 sex/height/weight entries, because I had to split them by sex to start, and I don't believe it will sort the same way. I am not sure how else to do it.

First I will create a data set.
set.seed(2024)
n <- 5000L
mdata <- matrix(c(rnorm(n), rnorm(n, 1)), ncol = 2L)
fdata <- matrix(c(runif(n), runif(n, 1, 2)), ncol = 2L)

msort <- sort(mdata[,2],decreasing = TRUE)
fsort<- sort(fdata[,2], decreasing = TRUE)
mt <- msort[1:20]
ms <- msort[4981:5000]
ft <- fsort[1:20]
fs <- fsort[4981:5000]

Created on 2024-10-09 with reprex v2.1.0

Now the ANOVA test.
Create a categorical vector grp corresponding to the vectors names, and put it in a data.frame along side with the numeric values above. Run the test using the formula interface.
As a data frame column vector name, height is probably better than y.
grp <- rep(c("mt", "ms", "ft", "fs"), each = 20L)
df1 <- data.frame(grp, y = c(mt, ms, ft, fs))

aov(y ~ grp, df1)
#> Call:
#>    aov(formula = y ~ grp, data = df1)
#> 
#> Terms:
#>                      grp Residuals
#> Sum of Squares  365.6578    1.4172
#> Deg. of Freedom        3        76
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.1365572
#> Estimated effects may be unbalanced

aov(y ~ grp, df1) |> summary()
#>             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
#> grp          3  365.7  121.89    6536 <2e-16 ***
#> Residuals   76    1.4    0.02                   
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

boxplot(y ~ grp, df1)


Created on 2024-10-09 with reprex v2.1.0

for the grp part, why are you needing to replicate that if you've already asked it to put 20 of each?

nevermind, I understand! I am gonna give this a go. Thank you!

@axr It's like, for instance, aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris). The grouping factor must be of the same length as the numeric vector of measurements.

@axr But note that with the same data (created with the same value in set.seed) the residual degrees of freedom and the residual sum of squares are the same in both answers.

Something like this perhaps?
set.seed(1)

mdata <- data.frame(1:5000, rnorm(5000) + 1)
fdata <- data.frame(1:5000, rnorm(5000))

msort <- sort(mdata[,2], decreasing = TRUE)
fsort <- sort(fdata[,2], decreasing = TRUE)

mt <- head(msort, 20)
ms <- tail(msort, 20)

ft <- head(fsort, 20)
fs <- tail(fsort, 20)

data <- data.frame(sex=rep(c("M","F"), each=40), 
                   ts=rep(c(rep("t", 20), rep("s", 20)), times=2),
                   x=c(mt,ms,ft,fs))

The test
summary(aov(x~sex*ts, data=data))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value Pr(>F)    
sex          1   17.1    17.1  228.398 <2e-16 ***
ts           1  690.9   690.9 9202.446 <2e-16 ***
sex:ts       1    0.1     0.1    0.713  0.401    
Residuals   76    5.7     0.1 


What is the *ts for in the formula part of the test?

@axr If you add sex + ts you get 1st order effec, if you multiply, sex * ts the formula expands to sex + ts + sex:ts and includes the interaction of sex and ts. Actually, I find this answer better than mine.
